# for loop, how do I make it print the word, not single alphabets?

Tags: python

```
def make_sandwiches():
    ingreds = []

    name = input("What is your name for your order? ")
    ingreds = input("What do you want for your sandwiches? ")
    print("Making " + name.title() + "'s sandwiches... ")

    ready = input("Please press 'r' when you're ready. ")
    if ready == 'r':
        **for ingred in ingreds:**
            print("we have put " + ingred.title() + ".")
    else:
        print("Thanks!")


make_sandwiches()
```

So when I run this and put `"ham, pepper"`, I get something like:

```
we have put H.
we have put A.
We have put M.
```

..... and so on.
How can I make this as `"we have put Ham.", "we have put pepper"`?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

```
for ingred in ingreds.split():
```

`ingreds` is just a string. Iterating over it as it is will produce its characters. If you want to iterate words (space-separated tokens) in the string, you have to `split` it first.

Answer (score 0):

To understand what is happening you can try:

```
for i in 'ham':
    print(i)
```

Versus:

```
for i in 'ham',:
    print(i)
```

Same results:

```
 for i in ['ham']:
     print(i)
```

The first will output characters in 'ham', h, a, m, as 'ham' is transformed to iteratable. The second and third with produce a full name because, you introduced ham as an iteratable in form of a tuple in second and list in third.

So to solve your problem, you need to change your variable to a iteratable.
Example:

```
'ham, pepper'.split(', ')
```

Results into:

```
 ['ham', 'pepper']
```

Hope that helps.